# timeseries averagein vertica

Tags: vertica

I have a table of stock prices over time with the fields: timestamp, price.

I could get the last value of the stock in each day like this:

```
SELECT slice_time, TS_LAST_VALUE(price, 'CONST') FROM StockPrices
TIMESERIES slice_time AS '1 day' over (ORDER BY timestamp)
```

What if I want the average price of the stock that day? Something like TS_AVG_VALUE...

Note this needs to work for any arbitrary time frame and not be hard coded for a duration of day.

Answer (score -1):

check out:
http://my.vertica.com/docs/6.0.0-1/HTML/index.htm#14430.htm

I think you could just do:

```
SELECT avg(TS_FIRST_VALUE(bid, 'LINEAR')) avg_bid FROM Tickstore
TIMESERIES slice_time AS '2 seconds' OVER(PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY ts);
```

The linearity, I think, would give you the desired averaging effect.

Comment: thanks - but this gives me the avg of everything (single value). I want the avg of each time slice (value per time slice).

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if you could partition by symbol and date(timestamp). Did you ever get an answer?